# How redirect using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How to redirect from one folder of one domain to another folder of another domain :
like :

http://www.abcdefg.in/fun/
to
http://www.abcdeefg.com/funny/

And it should work with wild card..

Comment: So, [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) so far?

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
Redirect /fun /funny
```

add a "301" after the `Redirect` if you want it permanent.

Comment: Do you think it will redirect all the urls ?